# TypeError: jasmine.arrayContaining is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, karma-jasmine

i am in trouble with jasmine 2.3 when running following expectation

```
expect([1,2,3]).toEqual(jasmine.arrayContaining([3,2]));
```

it says

```
TypeError: jasmine.arrayContaining is not a function
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Jasmine 2.3? How do you run it?

Comment: @EitanPeer. i'm using jasmin 2.3.2 and run it by karma

Comment: Can you share your Karma config file? Which Karma version are you using? Which karma-jasmine version?

Comment: @EitanPeer in the package.json i changed the line "karma-jasmine": "^0.2.3", to "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6", and the problem disappeared